# How to handle a pop up using selenium webdriver

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with a selenium webdriver to automate some process
while attempting to refresh a page , it is giving a popup.
On clicking of the 'retry' button in that popup, the page gets refreshed.
I want to know how to handle this popup to click on 'retry' button.

I could not post the image as I'm not having enough reputation points.

Update: Adding the image

[image]

Comment: Can you please upload the image to an external site? e.g. Imgur? Also what language are you writing in?

Comment: Is that javascript popup OR something like browser authentication / reload page confirmation window?

Comment: It is a javascript pop up. and I'm writing in Java.

Comment: Add the screenshot of the popup please. Use the image hosting website.

Comment: Sorry for that
imgur.com/tEwpqPs

Comment: Sorry for that
please find the image here
http://imgur.com/tEwpqPs

Answer (score 0):

Selenium's Alert Interface may suit your needs.

Here is an example usage that switches WebDriver's focus to an alert, and then accepts it.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Alert Interface:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html

Comment: I tried it. both accept() and dismiss() methods. It will go back to previous login screen from which i started testing

Comment: @Chetanj257: So, instead of previous login screen, where shall it navigate to ?

Comment: @Chetanj257 can you please post your code snippet , also can you try putting some sleep of 5 sec before driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); code

Answer (score 0):

You can try send key `alert.sendKeys("13")` to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> blindly

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.sendKeys("13");
```

Make also sure that Selenium Web Driver does not want to accept alert to early, it is common practice to do some wait (for couple of seconds) like @workspace said.

Other workaround for not invoke actions by selenium, is repeating it until it will be executed successfully. Of course with timeout, for example 30 sec.